# Azure ServiceBus vs ServiceRemoting, HTTP and WCF

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus, remoting

The [documentation of Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services) recommends service remoting, ICommunicationClient or WcfCommunicationClient to realize the communication between the micro services.

The ServiceBus, which I always used for inter-service communication, is not even mentioned. Why?

Answer (score 3):

I think you misinterpreted the docs. It does not *recommend* any protocol or service (the word is not even present on the page). What it does do is *list* the built-in communication options and appropriate situations of when to use them.

There is nothing that prevent you from using service bus for inter service communications. In fact, if you google around you will find some projects like [this one](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus)

The ability to plug in any desired service or protocol is one of the great things about SF, but they leave the implementation to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to do service to service communication, if they had to document all of then, they would spend more time writing the possible approaches than doing the actual communication.

They probably decided for the one with closest relation to the platform, but they could write about any possible, it is just a matter o preference.

I could name a few from many just to have an idea:

- Http
- Remoting
- WCF
- Service Bus
- Event Hub
- AMQP
- MQTT
- gRPC + protobuf
- TCP
- UDP
- Pipes

And many more, Imagine if they had to document all of then.

The communication is flexible enough to let you implement using any communication mechanism.

Regarding the ones you mentioned, 
I always opt for HTTP for being platform agnostic and widely implemented on most platforms, does not matter if is .Net, Java, NodeJs, Windows or Linux, they all talk the same language, the others are very tight to the .Net and Windows platform and force every other solution to be also tighten or adapted to then. And also there is the fact of some being synchronous and other asynchronous like Service bus.

Then, when performance is an issue, I evaluate the other options.