# Service Remoting in Azure Service Fabric vs RestFul calls

Tags: rest, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to understand the specific use cases of for using service remoting in azure service fabric vs make restful calls. Any insights into the performance, security and any relevant aspects is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets take a look. When it comes to communication between external clients and SF services I would use restful calls, because service remoting is specific to SF and restful apis can be consumed on almost every platform using any language.

For communication between services inside SF you could use Service Remoting. Basically it is a .NET RPC implementation for Service Fabric, see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52898817/932728). You can use other mechanisms but this one is provided out-of-the box and gives you a baked in retry policy and service resolution and more.

But it is hard to give a final recommendation because it will depend on the kind of service and its purpose. Sometimes you want direct communication using remoting for example and sometimes you want to have a message bus in between two services.

The most important takeaway would be to use https for communication to the cluster, so for public accessible SF services.

More background reading:

[Connect and communicate with services in Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services)

[Secure service remoting communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-secure-communication)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the purpose of the communication, so the answers can be very broad:

Technically,

**REST**

REST communication is universal, can be used by any client on any platform, is the better way to expose your services to clients outside the SF cluster using the HTTP protocol.

The service can evolve without breaking the compatibility to existing clients, there is no hard contract between the Client and the Service.

The problem with this approach for Service to Service communication is that the service must expose an HTTP server to receive REST calls and every call is serialized to JSON. An http server must have some routing rules to redirect the calls to the right handler, adding a lot of stuff to the service that shouldn't need it in simple scenarios.

**SF Remoting**

SF Remoting is an implementation of .Net Remoting, a component of .Net to provide binary communication over TCP. It is much faster because it does not need to serialize the data to JSON and validate all json rules for serialization.

The usage is a simple Interface Implementation between the service and the client. You don't need to host an HTTP server and configure routing rules for it, so the usage is much simpler.

The disadvantages,

The first problem with Remoting is that the Client and the Service must talk the same language, in this case .Net (PS: you could use other languages as well, but is not something straight forward), and also talk about the same subject, this is why both need access to a contract (Interface) that will tell how they should communicate to each other. This couple the client to the service, and an update is likely to happen on both sides at same time.

Second, because of the first, you are limited to .Net and also Service Fabric, you can't run SF Remoting outside a cluster, it is highly coupled to the SF Runtime.

Remoting works on a level underneath the HTTP protocol, the risk to expose it to internet is higher than an HTTP server. Does not mean it is unsecure, but it does not receive upgrades as often as WebServers does.

**In Summary,**

Use Remoting if you want performance and simple communication between services.

Use REST If you don't want the client coupled to the services and flexibility to be used by any client\platform.

Or, maybe you can use other protocols. This SO have some info that might be useful: [Azure ServiceBus vs ServiceRemoting, HTTP and WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594823/azure-servicebus-vs-serviceremoting-http-and-wcf/52595655#52595655)